# Generate C# from proto files and vice versa interpreting custom options

Tags: c#, code-generation, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), and I'm trying to:

1. Generate a C# class from a .proto file
2. Generate a .proto file from a C# class

That's pretty easy using respectively:

1. `protogen.exe` tool
2. `Serializer<T>.GetProto()` method

But the thing is that I need to support protobuffer [custom options](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#options) and it doesn't seem to be as straightforward as I though.

Let me explain:

1. From a proto file containing custom options applied on messages and fields, I want to generate a C# class decorated by .NET custom attributes.
2. From a C# class decorated by custom attributes, I would like to generate a proto file where custom options are applied on messages and fields.

Basically, given:

```
message person {
   option (my_message_option) = true;

   optional string firstname = 1 [(my_field_option) = 42];
   optional string lastname = 2 [(my_field_option) = 12];
   optional int age = 3;
}
```

I want to generate:

```
[ProtoContract, MyMessageOption(true)]
public class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1), MyFieldOption(42)]
    public string Firstname;

    [ProtoMember(2), MyFieldOption(12)]
    public string Firstname;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Firstname;
}
```

...and vice versa.

Notes :

- The custom option definitions
  (`my_message_option` and
  `my_field_option`) can already exist
  in a protofile (say,
  my_custom_options.proto), and the
  custom attributes classes can also
  exist somewhere
  (`MyMessageOptionAttribute` and
  `MyFieldOptionAttribute`).
- I tried to use protogen.exe and a
  custom xslt but protogen doesn't seem
  to have support for custom options.

What's the preferred way to achieve that? **The solution doesn't have to rely on protobuf-net.**

Comment: I want to do the same thing, to generate a decorated C# file (for protobuf-net) from a proto file. Could you give an exapme of how you achieved this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up by forking ProtoGen project from [protobuf-csharp](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) to make public some internal types (generators, for the most part) and to make the `SourceGenerators` extensible by allowing custom generator registrations.

This way, I was able to use the proto descriptor object model to write my own C# generator.

One tricky point is to register your custom options types before launching the parsing :

1. Generate C# types corresponding to your custom options (using `Protoc.exe` then `ProtoGen.exe`)
2. Configure `ExtensionRegistry` by using the generated `RegisterAllExtensions` methods.
3. Start the code generation using your own C# generators. In each generator you can access to the contextual `Descriptor.Options` collection.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way to do this at the moment. The changes required would primarily be to the csharp.xslt file. There is a bug [reported](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=156) about this but hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: I already tried to create a specific xslt file, but I can't have access to the custom options used in the proto file. Can you think of another solution non protobuf-net based?

Comment: @Romain this isn't a configuration I've had chance to look at, so: not off the top of my head, no. If you run it through the xml template (`-t:xml` or something similar), it will show you what it knows, which might indicate where this data is lurking - *assuming* it doesn't need an update to the descriptors.

Comment: Yep, that's what I tried (`-t:xml`) but all custom options appear as `uninterpreted_option` in the resulting xml file.